# has_secure_password prevents setting a boolean to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email-verification

I want to do email confirmation, after having set up sign in/sign up and sessions using the has_secure_password and authenticate method. 
I have a user model, and I added a confirmed boolean. When a user is created, I set their confirmed boolean to false, and send them an email with a link. Clicking the link generates a GET request to /users/:id/confirm, and executes the code of "confirm" action in the users_controller that is the following :

```
def confirm
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(confirmed: true)
    if @user.save 
      sign_in(@user)
      flash[:success] = "Your account has been successfully confirmed"
    else
      flash[:error] = "There has been a problem confirming your account "
    end 
     redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Very simple (I will do verification token later). My problem is that my user is never saved.

```
@user.errors.full_messages
```

returns :

```
["Password is too short", "Password confirmation can't be blank"]
```

How can I change a user object without having to edit their password each time ? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using update_attribute instead of update_attributes.

```
  @user.update_attribute(:confirmed, true)
```

Comment: ...and don't save twice. `update_attribute` already does saving -- no need to call `@user.save`. Remove the latter and check the result of `update_attribute` instead.