# Rails 4 has_secure_password and updating users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model really close to Michael Hartl's one

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 } 
  validates :about, length: { maximum: 300 }

  ...
end
```

When trying to `update_attributes` of an user, I can only do so if I also provide a password and  its password_confirmation.

Although I understand this is the expected behavior for User creation, there are some User properties that are to be set without its consent, hence his password.

How is one supposed to achieve that ? I looked for something like `has_secure_password, on: :create` but it doesn't work.

### Edit 1

Oddly enough, I can save a single attribute at a time, using `update_attribute` instead (which is still quiet a pain, I hope we can do better ) !

### Edit 2

I forgot to mention that I tried removing `has_secure_password` when updating and it works great, so it's definitely the culprit here. Is there an option I'm missing out here ? Should I look at its source code ?

### Update : Some console excerpts

```
irb(main):002:0> User.find(1).update_attribute(:confirmed_email, true)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction

irb(main):003:0> User.find(1).update_attributes(:confirmed_email => true)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('example@railstutorial.org') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> false

irb(main):004:0> User.find(1).update_attributes(:confirmed_email => true, password: 'NewPassword', password_confirmation: 'NewPassword')
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('example@railstutorial.org') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password_digest`
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "password_digest" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 1  [["password_digest", "$2a$10$CMxLD91SCHWcdhJ3ciU2jez4Zw.gD7o3JszBuOf0gY04MVap56dGy"], ["updated_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 21:38:36 UTC +00:00]]
   (172.4ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475333/rails-update-attributes-using-has-secure-password

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work; Ijust realized I'm actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386092/has-secure-password-prevents-setting-a-boolean-to-true. Should I delete ?

Comment: I wouldn't as that approach would require you to do a update_attribute for each field you're trying to update. Seems you might have a different issue on your hands. Just thought it might have been related to the one that I posted. Can we see your controller or any other relevant code?

Comment: I can't do it even in the console, so the controller should not be relevant here, right ?